# Comparing two ways of creating `ClientAnchor` in POI excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In `poi`, I am curious to know when [`CreationHelper#createClientAnchor()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html) is helpful. An example would be appreciated.

`ClientAnchor` can be created using [`Drawing#createAnchor(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Drawing.html), and to me, that is a logical place as `Drawing` is per `Sheet` and anchor is needed for drawings.

What I don't understand is the use case of `CreationHelper#createClientAnchor()`, especially as `CreationHelper` is per `Workbook`.